# How to set DynamoDB read consistency in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, consistency

Is there a way to set [DynamoDB read consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) (eventually vs strongly) mode in CloudFormation? I couldn't find how to do it in [CF doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html), but couldn't find a clear saying that CF does NOT support it either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not part of CloudFormation nor is it part of table schema definition.

Read Consistency is a flag you add when querying the data;

Global Secondary Indexes do not support strong consistent reads at all;

Comment: oh got it. i thought there is a table property that makes all reads strongly consistent. thanks!